# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) - Page not showing in production

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, .net-core

When I try to open some sub-pages (not all of the sub-pages here, just few) I have the following error on the console and the sub-page is not loading in:

jquery-3.4.1.js:9837          GET https://myWebSite.com/Admin/PageSelector?selectedPage=Accounts&_=1651327661366 net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

On localhost it works perfectly.
The application is .Net Core and the server is Ubuntu.

I've tried in Chrome and Edge too, the result is the same.

Do you have any idea where I can find the solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found a the issue. But it's strange.

If I have the few lines which have been generated by default when I've created the views:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_newLayout.cshtml";
}
```

then I have the above Error. But only on production, on localhost works fine with or without these lines.
If I remove these lines, the view works fine on production too.